# db2 function not working

Tags: db2

I created the function below to process a comma delimited string and create one single string. For example, if the string is "1,2,34,5,67" the output of this function should be "0102340567".

Db2 version is 9.1

```
create function fn_get_betnum (chartext varchar(100))
LANGUAGE SQL    
RETURNS VARCHAR(100)
DETERMINISTIC NO EXTERNAL ACTION
BEGIN atomic

    declare pos int;
    declare sep char(1);
    declare input varchar(100);
    declare s varchar(72);

    set sep=',';
    set input=trim(chartext);
    set pos = locate(sep,input);

    while pos > 0
    do
        set s=concat(s,right(concat('0',trim(substr(input,1,pos-1))),2));
        set input=substr(input,pos+1,length(input)-pos);
        set pos = locate(sep,input);
    end while;
    if length(input) > 0 then
        set s=concat(s,right(concat('0',trim(input)),2));
    end if;
    return s;
end
```

The function is created successfully, but when I try the following query I get an empty result set:

**Query:**

select fn_get_betnum('1,2') from my_table fetch first 1 rows only

**Result set:**

```
1
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-

  1 record(s) selected.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: So what's the rule about what you're doing? If you find a digit followed by a comma `2,` you replace it with `02`, so any character followed by a comma, gets a zero put in front of it? There are never two commas in a row?

Comment: only if it is a single digit number. If it is a 2 digits number no need of appending '0'. For example "1,2,34,5,56" should become 0102340556

Comment: @user2758122 I am sure someone had a reason to give you a -1 but I think the issue you are running into is interesting. On DB2 v6r1 (iSeries/AS400) I am seeing results that are weird and worth investigating. So +1 from me; it made me think about other oddities with UDFs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't initialize the variable `s`, this line:

```
    set s=concat(s,right(concat('0',trim(substr(input,1,pos-1))),2));
```

will always be null. As @zfus has shown, initialize `s` to an empty string:

```
    declare s varchar(100) default '';
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one you could try. I tried to simplify it a little. Disclaimer: this works fine on DB2 v6r1 (iSeries/AS400). DB2 on LUW or z-Series may need some modification to the function below:

```
create function fn_get_betnum (chartext varchar(100))
returns varchar(100)
language sql
deterministic no external action
begin

    declare pos int;
    declare sep char(1) default ',';
    declare temp varchar(10);
    declare s varchar(100) default '';

    -- get position of comma
    set pos = locate(sep, chartext);

    -- loop till no comma is found
    while pos > 0 do

        -- get the left side before comma
        set temp = left(chartext, pos-1);
        if length(trim(temp)) = 1 then 
            set temp = '0' || temp;
        end if;     
        set s = s || temp;

        -- throw away the first command and everything before that
        set chartext = substr(chartext, pos+1, 100);

        -- find the next comma
        set pos = locate(sep, chartext);

    end while;

    -- take the remainder of the string after no comma
    -- is found and stick it behind the text to return
    if length(trim(chartext)) = 1 then
        set chartext = '0' || chartext;
    end if;
    set s = s || chartext;

    return s;
end;
```

The result:

```
select fn_get_betnum('1,2,34,5,67') from sysibm/sysdummy1;
```

results in:
`0102340567`